# Store view default currency doesn't change in admin while adding product?

Tags: product, price, store-view

I have created 5-6 store view with single currency in all of then
e.g Yen for japan, CAD for canada.

Every thing works fine , but while adding product from admin and selecting the respective store view then in price tab it always show USD . Please check the attached snapshot.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Price scope in Magento Catalog can be defined globally or per Website, not per Store view.

Go to `System > Configuration > Catalog > Price (Default Config)` and change Catalog Price Scope.

Then setup Base Currency for each website in `System > Configuration > Currency Setup`.